# Infinite square well plane wave solutions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

In the Sommerfeld free electron model, we assume the electrons are free, independent and confined to a volume $V=l^3$. We then solve the Schrodinger equation for the infinite cubic well and apply the Born von Karman boundary conditions
$$\psi(x,y,z)=\psi(x+l,y,z)\,\,\,\,\psi(x,y,z)=\psi(x,y+l,z)\,\,\,\, \psi(x,y,z)=\psi(x,y,z+l).$$

These boundary conditions then alter the solutions of the Schrodinger equation  by changing them from the usual standing wave equations (which we get when we use the boundary conditions $\psi(\vec{r})=0$ for all $\vec{r}$ outside the volume V) to plane wave solutions of the form
$$\psi_k(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}}.$$

My problem is I can't seem to get solutions of this form to come out when apply the von Karman boundary conditions and I can't seem to find any derivation that does. Everytime, the author simply states that the solutions are plane wave solutions but never derives these solutions. When I attempt to solve the problem using separation of variables and I apply the von Karman boundary conditions, I get 3 equations (1 for each variable) of the form

$$A_xe^{ik_x(x+l)}+B_xe^{-ik_x(x+l)}=A_xe^{ik_xx}+B_xe^{-ik_xx}.$$

But then there doesn't seem to be any way to manipulate these equations into the plane wave solutions that authors posit. I realize my maths is probably the issue but if anyone could show me how to manipulate the above so that I get plane wave solutions it would be most appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\psi(x,y,z)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$ the differential equation for $X(x)$ is

$$\frac{1}{X(x)}\frac{d^2X(x)}{dx^2}=-k_x^2,\tag{1}$$

whose general solution neglecting the boundary condition is

$$X(x)=A_x e^{ik_x x}+B_x e^{-ik_x x}.\tag{2}$$

Instead of having a negative constant on the RHS, you could have tried with a positive one, but the solution wouldn't satisfy the required boundary conditions.

Then, imposing Born-Von Karman boundary conditions as you did, you get

$$A_x e^{ik_x x}(e^{ik_x l}-1)+B_x e^{-ik_x x}(e^{-ik_x l}-1)=0,\tag{3}$$

which is your result but written in another way. If you want this to hold for any $A_x$ and $B_x$, you need $e^{\pm ik_x l}=1$, which is satisfied if $k_x=\frac{2\pi}{l}n_x$ with $n_x\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now you have a set of independent functions that are solution of $(1)$ and satisfy Born-von Karman BC, i.e.

$$X_{n_x}(x)=e^{ik_x x}~~~,~~~k_x=\frac{2\pi}{l}n_x~~~,~~~n_x=0,\pm1,\pm2...\, .\tag{4}$$

There is no other function independent of $(4)$ that satisfy $(1)$ and the boundary conditions.

Doing the same for $Y(y)$ and $Z(z)$, you get $$\psi(x,y,z)=De^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}},$$

where each component of $\vec{k}$ is $\frac{2\pi}{l}n_i$ with $n_i=0,\pm1,\pm2...$

Comment: Thanks for the response and the help! I'm just a little confused as to why you can change $X(x)=A_xe^{ik_x x}+B_xe^{-ik_xx}$ into $X(x)=Ce^{ik_xx}$ ? Surely the exponentials in your first equation can still have different phases since $A_x,B_x \in C$? That would mean that the sum of the two exponentials in your first equation is simply the sum of two plane waves travelling in opposite directions with arbitrary phases and amplitudes however their wavelengths are restricted by the condition $k_x=2\pi/l n_x$. Why do we get to just drop one of the plane waves and assume that $X(x)=Ce^{ik_xx}$ ?

Comment: @SalahTheGoat I edited my answer to make things more clear.

Comment: Thanks. Okay I am with you more or less but still a touch confused on equation 4. Its clear to me that $k_x=\frac{2\pi}{l}n_x$ for integers $n_x$. My thinking is that we should then get $X(x)=A_x e^{i\frac{2\pi}{l}n_xx}+B_x e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{l}n_x x}$ for integers $n_x $as the general solution to your first equation. But this does not in general equal to $X(x)=Ce^{i2\pi/l\,n_x}$. So have we not lost some of the solution space in dropping the second exponential? Also when you say independent do you mean linearly independent? Once again, thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You can get your $X(x)$ as a linear combination of the $X_{n_x}(x)$, i.e. $X(x)=A_x X_{n_x}(x)+B_x X_{-n_x}(x)$. We could take your $X(x)$ or the $X_{n_x}(x)$ to describe the eigenfunctions, since both satisfy $(1)$, but $X_{n_x}$ have the advantage of also being eigenfunctions of $p_x$ (or $k_x$).